# Same binary code on Windows and Linux (x86)

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, linker, g++

I want to compile a bunch of C++ files into raw machine code and the run it with a platform-dependent starter written in C. Something like

```
fread(buffer, 1, len, file);
a=((*int(*)(int))buffer)(b);
```

How can I tell g++ to output raw code?

Will function calls work? How can I make it work?

I think the calling conventions of Linux and Windows differ. Is this a problem? How can I solve it?

EDIT: I know that PE and ELF prevent the DIRECT starting of the executable. But that's what I have the starter for.

Comment: not going to happen - two completely different object file formats

Comment: While I am not qualified to answer, it certainly seems that something like this should be possible.  If I can write code that does not depend upon any standard library, as if for an embedded system perhaps, it should then be runnable on any x86 chip, no?

Comment: See this question http://superuser.com/questions/209703/why-wont-windows-exes-work-on-linux -- The short answer ELF (linux) vs. PE (windows)

Comment: there's much more to a file that has executable code in it than just the machine-level instructions.  data segments, etc.  therefore that file has to be compatible with your platform, which means it needs to be either ELF or PE.  In other words, you can save a binary blob file with machine instructions and run it, even if you have a platform-dependant launcher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one (relatively) simple way of achieving some of this, and that's called "position independent code". See your compiler documentation for this.

Meaning you can compile some sources into a binary which will execute no matter where in the address space you place it. If you have such a piece of x86 binary code in a file and `mmap()` it (or the Windows equivalent) it is possible to invoke it from both Linux and Windows.

Limitations already mentioned are of course still present - namely, the binary code must restrict itself to using a calling convention that's identical on both platforms / can be represented on both platforms (for 32bit x86, that'd be passing args on the stack and returning values in EAX), and of course the code must be fully self-contained - no DLL function calls as resolving these is system dependent, no system calls either.

I.e.:

1. You need position-independent code
2. You must create self-contained code without any external dependencies
3. You must extract the machine code from the object file.

Then `mmap()` that file, initialize a function pointer, and `(*myblob)(someArgs)` may do.

If you're using gcc, the `-ffreestanding -nostdinc -fPIC` options should give you most of what you want regarding the first two, then use objdump to extract the binary blob from the ELF object file afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, some of this is achievable. However there are so many gotchas along the way that it's not really a practical solution for anything.

- System call formats are totally incompatible
- DEP will prevent data executing as code
- Memory layouts are different
- You need to effectively dynamically 'relink' the code before you can run it.
- .. and so forth...

Comment: Do you have links? I thought I could pass a function pointer to the included code that points to a function that does platform dependent things. Like system calls.

Answer (score 1):

The same executable cannot be run on both Windows and Linux.

You write your code platform independently (STL, Boost & Qt can help with this), then compile in G++ on Linux to output a linux-binary, and similarly on a compiler on the windows platform.

EDIT: Also, perhaps these two posts might help you:

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180242/tips-resources-for-large-scale-cross-platform-software-projects/4180472#4180472)

[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186643/linux-windows-cross-c-application/4186699#4186699)

Comment: what makes the two platforms incompatible? both use x86.

Comment: x86 is a family of instruction-set architectures and has nothing to do with the structure of the executable and operating system.  I've updated my post with some other answers I've posted regarding cross-platform programming.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you take a look at wine? It's for using windows executables on Linux. Another solution for that is using Java or .NET bytecode.

You can run .NET executables on Linux (requires mono runtime)

Also have a look at Agner's objconv (disassembling, converting PE executable to ELF etc.)
http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv

Answer (score 1):

Someone actually figured this out. It’s called αcτµαlly pδrταblε εxεcµταblε (APE) and you use the Cosmopolitan C library. The gist is that there’s a way to cause Windows PE executable headers to be ignored and treated as a shell script. Same goes for MacOS allowing you to define a single executable. Additionally, they also figured out how to smuggle ZIP into it so that it can incrementally compress the various sections of the file / decompress on run.

https://justine.lol/ape.html
https://github.com/jart/cosmopolitan

Example of a single identical Lua binary running on Linux and Windows:
https://ahgamut.github.io/2021/02/27/ape-cosmo/

Answer (score 0):

Doing such a thing would be rather complicated. It isn't just a matter of the cpu commands being issued, the compiler has dependencies on many libraries that will be linked into the code. Those libraries will have to match at run-time or it won't work.

For example, the STL library is a series of templates and library functions. The compiler will inline some constructs and call the library for others. It'd have to be the exact same library to work.

Now, in theory you could avoid using any library and just write in fundamentals, but even there the compiler may make assumptions about how they work, what type of data alignment is involved, calling convention, etc.

Don't get me wrong, it can work. Look at the WINE project and other native drivers from windows being used on Linux. I'm just saying it isn't something you can quickly and easily do.

Far better would be to recompile on each platform.

Answer (score -1):

That is achievable only if you have [WINE](http://www.winehq.org/) available on your Linux system. Otherwise, the difference in the executable file format will prevent you from running Windows code on Linux.